# Can I resize, pad a video and overlay an image in one step with FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an input video that is recorded at 640x360 (it's from a webcam if that makes any difference).

I want the output to be 1280x720 (double the width of the original) and I want the original video to be shifted to the right and centered vertically.

I have two or more images (png) that are 640x720 and they should be shown at certain times in the video on the left side.

Here's what I have to re-size and pad the original video:

```
ffmpeg -i "E:\Videos\testvid.wmv" -q:a 0 -q:v 0 -vf "pad=1280:720:(1280-iw):(720-ih)/2" -s 1280:720 "E:\Videos\new.wmv"
```

Here's what I have to insert an image into the video:

```
ffmpeg -i "E:\Videos\new.wmv" -i "E:\Pictures\red_640x720.png" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,10)'" "E:\Videos\new2.wmv"
```

The two statements above work fine. However, I would like to do them all at once so FFMPEG only runs once (if this is possible). Can anyone lend me a hand with the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connect filters with commas. A linear sequence of one or more filters makes a filterchain. Connect filterchains with semicolons to create a filtergraph. See [Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) and [Filtergraph Description](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) for more detailed info.

Example:

```
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]filter_0,filter_1,filter_2[chain1]; \
 [1:v]filter_3,filter_4,filter_5[chain2]; \
 [chain1][chain2]filter_6"
```

So your command could look like:

```
ffmpeg -i video.wmv -i image0.png -i image1.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih*2:ow-iw:(oh-ih)/2[padded]; \
 [padded][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,1,10)'[bg]; \
 [bg][2:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,10,20)'[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a output.wmv
```

Resulting in:

[image: an overlay overlaid over an overlay]